# "I'm no more hungry" or "I'm no longer hungry" or "I'm hungry no more."

Tags: word-choice, grammar, idioms, word-order

> I'm no more hungry

I don't think I've heard the first one very often, but wasn't sure about the last two.

> I'm no longer hungry
>   and
>   I'm hungry no more

Which of these three sentences should I use? Which sound more natural? Are all three grammatically correct? Which one is the most idiomatic?

Comment: You should consider visiting our sister site, [ell.se], which is directed especially towards ESL learners and the kinds of questions and doubts they tend to have. This site is intended for questions that deal with more complex and harder-to-describe issues in the English language, and many of the questions you have asked here would really be much better suited for [ell.se].

Comment: I would most likely say "I'm not hungry any more". You could say "I'm no longer hungry", but that has a slightly more formal, stuffier feel.

Comment: You cannot just say “Which one should I use?” without providing a surrounding context that would recommend one over another: you didn’t specify **use *for what***. Otherwise you’ll get rescue readings the likes of “After gobbling down that entire turducken, I’m no more hungry than a goose after his final fortnight of gavage just prior to harvesting his foie gras.”

Comment: This question suffers from ⓵ Not enough context ⓶ Not enough research ⓷ Posting to [elu.se] which is **“Q&A for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”*** instead of posting it to [ell.se] which is **“Q&A for speakers of other languages *learning* English”**. If you need nothing but a fluent speaker’s ear to pass judgment on your non-native speaker’s English formulations, then you don’t need [elu.se] at all. You might not even need [ell.se], for if only you had exercised due diligence by way of prior research, you probably wouldn’t even have needed to ask.

Comment: Hell hath no fury like tchrist!

Comment: Look at this [Ngram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+no+more+hungry%2CI%27m+no+longer+hungry%2CI%27m+hungry+no+more&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20no%20longer%20hungry%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20'm%20no%20longer%20hungry%3B%2Cc1) it's pretty clear who's the winner.

Answer (score 1):

“I'm no more hungry”

I would only use this construction in something like “I'm no more hungry than I was yesterday”. I would never use it to mean "I am not hungry" or "I am no longer hungry"

---

“I'm no longer hungry”

This means I was hungry but now I am not hungry

It is the usual way of saying this.

---

“I'm hungry no more.”

This too means "I was hungry but now I am not hungry". It is not in common use. To me it sounds a bit poetic and pretentious.

Answer (score -3):

There are four possibilities that all mean the same.
I'm no more/no longer hungry or I'm not hungry anymore/any longer.

Comment: “I’m no more hungry” is not idiomatic, at least not in this sense. You can use it in contexts like “I’m no more hungry than blond” (if you have brown hair and you’re not hungry at all).

Comment: No, "*I'm no more hungry*" doesn't work (you'd only use it in a comparative way: "*I'm no more hungry than you are.*"). Also, none of your four suggestions is particularly common, and the OP is looking for a *natural* (idiomatic) phrasing, not one which is merely technically correct.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written: I'm not hungry any more or I'm hungry no more. It's a long time that I have used those formulas.

Comment: @Rogermue, no one really say "I'm hungry no more." Except in bad fan fiction.

Comment: All the same, it is possible.

Comment: It's possible to say: "Hungry I am no more" but nobody says it! Why don't you edit your answer?